# Using a switch with file in Python

Tags: python, file, switch-statement

I have written this code in C. It selects a file to read the data from and run the program with the data selected. I want to write this in Python, I found some tutorials, but all of them refers to printing messages using a switch. Can you help me with this?

```c
switch (alegere)
    {
    case 'a':
        F=fopen("date1.txt", "r");//deschidere fisier pentru citire
        break;
    case 'b':
        F=fopen("date2.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'c':
        F=fopen("date3.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'd':
        F=fopen("date4.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'e':
        F=fopen("date5.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'f':
        F=fopen("date6.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'g':
        F=fopen("date7.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'h':
        F=fopen("date8.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'i':
        F=fopen("date9.txt", "r");
        break;
    case 'j':
        F=fopen("date10.txt", "r");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Input invalid");
        exit(1);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: python doesn't have switch satement instead you can use dictionary in your case

Comment: Python does not have `switch` statement. Read about `if-else` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use dict to do the selection

```
file_paths = {
    'a': 'date1.txt',
    'b': 'date2.txt',
}
file_path = file_paths.get(alegere)
if not file_path:
    printf("Input invalid");
    exit(1)

with open(file_path, 'r') as fin:
    # do sth
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple dictionary

```py
adict = {a:fonctionA, b:fonctionB, ...}

aDict['d'] = fonctionD
```

Dictionnaries can take objects like fonctions...

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, you can use this:

```
OFFSET = 96
file_no = ord(alegere) - OFFSET
file_name = f"date{file_no}.txt"

if file_no in range(1, 11):
    fh = open(file_name)
else:
    print("Input invalid")
```

The `OFFSET` helps map the letters to numbers i.e. `a => 1, b => 2,..`. Since "a" corresponds to 97 in ASCII table, we subtract 96.